# Is this a good way to clean up the various Eclipse release name/version tags?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I noticed the following tag synonyms already in place for various Eclipse releases:

- [eclipse-ganymede](/questions/tagged/eclipse-ganymede) -> [eclipse-3.4](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.4)
- [eclipse-galileo](/questions/tagged/eclipse-galileo) -> [eclipse-3.5](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.5)
- [eclipse-helios](/questions/tagged/eclipse-helios) -> [eclipse-3.6](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.6)

Seems like there is a pattern going on there, with the codename for each release being synonymous to its version number. But based on the state of the rest of the Eclipse release tags, I'm not sure whether the pattern has been fully established yet. So I would suggest the following:

- Merge [eclipse-europa](/questions/tagged/eclipse-europa) (6 questions, no wiki) -> [eclipse-3.3](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.3) (7 questions, and I just suggested a wiki excerpt).
- Possibly merge [eclipse-indigo](/questions/tagged/eclipse-indigo) -> [eclipse-3.7](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.7). (Caveats: [eclipse-3.7](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.7) is currently unused, but this would standardize the pattern already in place— see above. The wiki from [eclipse-indigo](/questions/tagged/eclipse-indigo) would also need to be transferred, unless that happens automatically.)
- Possibly merge [eclipse-callisto](/questions/tagged/eclipse-callisto) -> [eclipse-3.2](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.2). (Caveat: [eclipse-callisto](/questions/tagged/eclipse-callisto) is currently unused and unlikely to be used anytime soon.)
- Possibly merge [eclipse-juno](/questions/tagged/eclipse-juno) -> [eclipse-4.2](/questions/tagged/eclipse-4.2), if I understand the [Simultaneous Release schedule](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release) correctly. (Caveats: [eclipse-4.2](/questions/tagged/eclipse-4.2) is currently unused. The wiki from [eclipse-juno](/questions/tagged/eclipse-juno) would also need to be transferred.)

Is this a good way to organize the Eclipse release tags?