# Request for merging tags "ganymede", "eclipse-europa", and "galileo" into eclipse tags

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I feel these can be merged as follows to resolve the ambiguity and avoid verbose tagging. What do you think?

> **Synonym...............Original..............Merged TagName**
>         [ganymede](/questions/tagged/ganymede)..............[eclipse-3.4](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.4)........[eclipse-3.4](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.4)
>         [eclipse-europa](/questions/tagged/eclipse-europa).......[eclipse-3.3](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.3)........[eclipse-3.3](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.3)
>        [galileo](/questions/tagged/galileo).....................[eclipse-3.5](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.5)........[eclipse-3.5](/questions/tagged/eclipse-3.5)

[Supporting Wiki Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases)

Comment: I noticed this "group of synonymous tags" / preferred tag relationship when doing work on Music tagging.  Some of my co-workers were very passionate about using the "Wild West" un-curated method of tagging.  And yet, the possible advantages of creating a tag object with a list of synonyms and a preferred tag were great in terms of someone being able to see all the relavent answers to their query.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111422/is-this-a-good-way-to-clean-up-the-various-eclipse-release-name-version-tags

Comment: @JasonPlank, while i agree it is related to the link, the OP tags [ganymede], [eclipse-europa] and [galileo] are neither part of the synonym list nor the suggested synonyms. I have also observed user doing verbose tagging, e.g they tag ganymede and eclipse 3.4, hence this post. What's your opinion on these ?

Comment: @Vimal I think I do have [eclipse-europa] in the list to my question, but not the others :). I prefer the numbered versions, e.g. [eclipse-3.5]. I think there should be just one tag for each release. Tagging [ganymede] + [eclipse-3.4] seems redundant.